# How to enable fast forward - dont know enough about git to solve this

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've asked a variation of this before and I was not able to resolve it.  And everything I have done seems to make the situation worse.

I have a staging branch and I'd like to make it fast forward into master.

This was set up by someone else so I just operate it :)

[image: What I see in bitbucket]

How can I resolve this so that any changes I make in staging will be able to fast forward into master?

Edit: Thanks in advance for helping.  Note that I know very little about git so please dont assume I know how to do even the most basic things.

Answer (score 0):

You can fast forward branch A into branch B if A's history hasn't forked from B, and if A is behind B :

```
# example 1 : master and staging haven't forked,
#     master can be "fast forwarded" to staging :
--*--*--*--*--*--* <- staging
     ^
   master

# example 2 : master and staging have forked,
#     master can't be fast forwarded to staging anymore :
          *--*--* <- staging
         /
--*--*--*
         \
          *--* <- master
```

So the general rule you are looking for is something like :

- `master` should only be updated by fast forwarding to some version of `staging`

---

If your repo contains the code of a product, and `master` represents the production version of your product, there will probably be exceptions to this rule.

For example : if a bug is spotted on `master`, and needs to be fixed without pulling all the current development of `staging`.

In that case, to "stitch back" your branches together, you can either merge `master` into `staging`, or rebase the work done on `staging` onto `master`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I dont really understand.  I mean I do only at the highest level. The way we were working is that code would change in the non master branches and then get pushed to master. But I think I accidentally made a change in master (like your point about fixing without pulling staging).  But I've tried merging staging into master and vice versa and it doesnt seem to fix this. And your comment about rebasing like greek to me.